# Import Data from Microsoft Graph API to Power BI

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, powerquery, powerbi-custom-data-connector

I have been trying to import data from Microsoft Graph API directly to Power BI. I have been given credentials for "Secret Key Name", "Secret Key", "Secret ID", "Client ID", "Tenant ID". This is my first time using M function so unable to get it right.

So far, I have followed methods from [this](https://powers-hell.com/2021/08/15/authenticate-to-graph-directly-from-powerbi/) webpage

I am trying to access URL:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users

I am getting the error:

```
An error occurred in the ‘’ query. DataFormat.Error: A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.

Details:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

I tried introducing Secret Key name in the Header section and given Secret Key while connecting the Web API but it is not working. I also tried creating extra parameter for Secret Key name and then giving Secret Key in Web API credential but it is not working as well.

Don't know what to do with these extra parameters of Secret Key name and Secret Key and where to enter them.

Comment: Please share the code, at least the part where you call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Comment: @user2250152 It's same as above. I invoke the given in the Invoke-GraphRequest function

Comment: can you pleae refer document for integrating MS graph with Power BI:  https://blog.mydock365.com/microsoft-graph-api-data-on-microsoft-power-bi#:~:text=Access%20Microsoft%20Graph%20API%20using%20Power%20BI%20Login,the%20data%20to%20Microsoft%20Power%20BI%20Desktop%20easily.: